# Selenium Grid is launching the wrong version of Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I'm trying to use Selenium Grid 3.0.1 with Firefox 47 on OS X. `/Applications/Firefox.app` is Firefox 50. `/Applications/Firefox 47.app` is Firefox 47. No matter what I try, Selenium launches `/Applications/Firefox.app`.

I've run the stand alone server in hub mode.

```
$ java -jar ~/Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role hub
14:54:03.419 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75'
14:54:03.420 INFO - Launching Selenium Grid hub
2016-12-14 14:54:04.042:INFO::main: Logging initialized @946ms
14:54:04.052 INFO - Will listen on 4444
2016-12-14 14:54:04.093:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.15.v20160210
2016-12-14 14:54:04.120:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4d49af10{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2016-12-14 14:54:04.141:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@29ba4338{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2016-12-14 14:54:04.142:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @1046ms
14:54:04.142 INFO - Nodes should register to http://192.168.1.10:4444/grid/register/
14:54:04.142 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
```

And then set up a node using Firefox 47.

```
$ java -jar ~/Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -browser browserName=firefox,version=47,firefox_binary=/Applications/Firefox\ 47.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
14:55:14.887 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75'
14:55:14.888 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
2016-12-14 14:55:15.470:INFO::main: Logging initialized @854ms
14:55:15.505 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
14:55:15.505 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
14:55:15.506 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
14:55:15.506 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registration is skipped:
Unable to create new instances on this machine.
14:55:15.506 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
14:55:15.506 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
2016-12-14 14:55:15.535:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.15.v20160210
2016-12-14 14:55:15.560:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@481a996b{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2016-12-14 14:55:15.587:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@7714e963{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:5555}
2016-12-14 14:55:15.587:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @971ms
14:55:15.587 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
14:55:15.612 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
14:55:15.612 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://localhost:4444/grid/register
14:55:15.657 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
14:55:25.822 INFO - SessionCleaner initialized with insideBrowserTimeout 0 and clientGoneTimeout 1800000 polling every 180000
```

I verified via `http://localhost:4444/grid/console` that the grid sees that node.

The hub sees the request for Firefox 47.

```
14:56:23.028 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=47, platform=ANY}]
14:56:23.029 INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {firefox_binary=/Applications/Firefox 47.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, version=47, platform=MAC}
```

And so does the node, but it launches `Firefox.app` instead.

```
14:56:23.041 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=47, platform=ANY}]])
14:56:23.049 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=47, platform=ANY}]
1481756183115   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:19913
14:56:23.141 INFO - Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
1481756183145   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path /var/folders/0b/7xp2lxbd7yl0tcpms06fr3d40000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.zhTJMwOyP59u
1481756183151   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can try initialzing firefox binary in  DesiredCapabilities;

```
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "firefox");
    capabilities.setCapability("firefox_binary", "{Full path to firefox binary}");
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + host + ":" + port + "/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: That looks like Java? I'm using the Perl client but had the equivalent as you can see from the Capabilities line in the hub and node logs... except for setting `marionette` to `false`. What does that do?

Comment: Rather than specifying the Path of firefox browser in command line for node, try giving the path while invoking browser at runtime. marionette=False is used for Firefox 47.